# 401 - Unauthorized in cypress io auto testing

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, http-status-code-401, cypress

First time to write a Cypress (cypress Io framework) auto test for internal website (http://XXXX:8089/). The access of this website homepage requires special permissions by using active directory (get the windows credential and check if the user belongs to a certain group or have the certain role). The testing script is pretty simple:

```
describe('The Home Page', function() {
it('successfully loads', function() {
cy.visit('http://XXXX:8089/')
  })
})
```

got the 401 -Unauthoized error message. Tried replacing url with embedded windows credential like http://username:password@xxxx:8089/, got the same error. Cannot find a solution through google. Hope someone can kindly help me solve this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Quick question, does the `http://username:password@xxxx:8089/` works if you paste the link into a chrome browser?

Comment: Yes. It will redirect to http://xxxx:8089/

Comment: Maybe related https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/850

Comment: Looks so similar to that one. So there is not any solutions available for this question so far?

Comment: The is a solution, but involves implementing some kind of proxy

Comment: Hackerman, Could you please tell me how?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this issue and fix by:

add {failOnStatusCode: false} will ignore the status because Cypress will stop the the run by any 40X status so with {failOnStatusCode: false} will told cypress to continue

```
cy.visit('/', {failOnStatusCode: false});
```

Comment: The error got resolved but now it is not taking the username and password from the url . any idea what would be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps anyone who face the issue.

```
cy.visit('http://XXXX:8089/', {
  auth: {
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin123',
  }
});
```

This one helps me solve the 401 Unauthorized issue. Apparently this helps you solve your issue when you're facing a [Basic Authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) when visiting a site.

Source: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Options

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way to log in before each test.

```js
const login = () => {
    cy.visit('http://0.0.0.0:8080/#/login');
    cy.get('#username').type('username');
    cy.get('#password').type('1234password$');
    cy.get('#login-button').click();
}

describe('UI', () => {
  // beforeEach(login);
    beforeEach(() => {
        login();
        Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session_id', 'remember_token');
  });

});
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the issue. You won't be able to find any of the DOM elements such as #username if the AD security is in place. The page won't load and you'll get a 401 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for my issue on GitHub. You can check it out here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/21213

Workaround can be add the `chromeWebSecurity: false` property

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10209180/223781724-9dbd7c12-d485-4e7e-b25e-7b9662199fdb.png]

on `cypress.config.js`:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  projectId: 'f11gqz',
  e2e: {
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
     
    },
  },
});
```